# Checking preprocessor directives with Android Studio Gradle Build, NDK and CMake

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I'm passing in preprocessor directives via `CMakeLists.txt` for the build of a native android library using android NDK.

```
add_definitions(-DMY_DIRECTIVE=1)
```

It would be great to double check that those preprocessor directives are actually finding their way into the calls to the compiler (llvm ?)

But the gradle build output doesn't seem to include the calls to the compiler, I just get:

```
Building C object CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/home/me/projects/my_proj/src/my_native.c.o
```

Is there a means to make the gradle output more verbose such that I can see the actual compiler calls and check those preprocessor directives are present?

Comment: You can use -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1 as explained in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44709786/301166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to understand that Gradle utilises CMake to build the android NDK component (shared library) of an android project, and CMake utilises Ninja as a build system to handle the calls to the compiler. The compiler used by android NDK now defaults to LLVM->Clang.

So in order to actually see the Clang calls you have to find the `build.ninja` files for each target of your android project.

In my case I am only building for an `armeabi-v7a` target architecture. Therefore the relevant `build.ninja` files are found in:

```
/home/me/projects/my_proj/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a
/home/me/projects/my_proj/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a
```

`cd` to either directory and run:

```
ninja -v
```

i.e. the `-v` option is the key to see all the calls to the clang compiler that the native build (android NDK) part of your android project generates.

Note if you have installed CMake via the android package manager, you may find that ninja is not installed in a location that is on your `PATH`. For me the ninja binary is located as follows:

```
~/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja
```

(same directory as cmake binary)

Therefore for me to see all the clang compiler calls for my android project's debug armeabi-v7a build I have to run:

```
cd /home/me/projects/my_proj/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a
~/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja -v
```

Note if ninja tells you `ninja: no work to do.`

Then run:

```
~/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja clean
```

Relevant ninja documentation is -> https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_extra_tools