# Running CMake from command line within an Android NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

How might one run an NDK Cmake build independently from the rest of an Android project, ideally from the command line, external to Android Studio?

The equivalent of running `ndk-build` from the jni directory for slightly older Android NDK projects.

I need to investigate exactly what the calls to the compiler look like, and I can't seem to get this information when building the whole project from within Android Studio

My first attempt was just to run cmake from the `project/app` directory containing `CMakeLists.txt`, but this informs me that `cmake` is not installed - so how is Android Studio managing to build it then?

Comment: ok - have now found the Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin directory - making progress..

Comment: This is a relevant and useful resource -> https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html#build-command

Comment: This may be relevant to what you're trying to do, although it's not the same as your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530158/how-do-you-get-the-full-set-of-compiler-and-linker-flags-used-by-ndk-build

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your goal is to just run from the command line (as opposed to trying to do *exactly* what gradle is doing), just use cmake the way you normally would:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
    -DANDROID_ABI=whatever $YOUR_SOURCE_DIR
```

Alternatively, you can just run `./gradlew` from the command line.

Comment: this is correct, but I discovered that the way to inspect the clang compiler calls was to step one level deeper and run the build.ninja files with the -v option

Comment: `-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-XXX` may also be necessary, where XXX is 21, or 16, or whatever you need.

Answer (score 5):

Your original problem is that you cannot see the command-line invocation when building with Android Studio.

You can get the command line arguments to the compiler by editing your app/build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            ...
            arguments "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1", ...
        }
    }

}
```

In Adroid Studio's Gradle Console pane, you will then see the command line for the compiler and linker like so:

[1/176] /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot   -isystem /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -marm -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC -MD -MT /home/bram/src/GPGOAP/CMakeFiles/gpgoap.dir/astar.c.o -MF /home/bram/src/GPGOAP/CMakeFiles/gpgoap.dir/astar.c.o.d -o /home/bram/src/GPGOAP/CMakeFiles/gpgoap.dir/astar.c.o   -c /home/bram/src/GPGOAP/astar.c

Comment: this is interesting as I did add set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on) to my CMakeLists.txt instead of the build.gradle file but it didn't seem to do anything. I assume that both approaches should effectively achieve the same end? I'll go back and double check..

Comment: Add a syntax error into your CMakeList.txt  file and Android Studio shows you the command line invokation. But not the cmake output :-(

Answer (score 3):

As detail to the accepted answer:

The complete set of parameters passed to CMake is written to:

```
<project-root>/<module-root>/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/<build-type>/<ABI>/cmake_build_command.txt`
```

See for details: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html#build-command