# How do you get the full set of compiler and linker flags used by ndk-build?

Tags: android-ndk

Is there a straightforward way to get the full set of compile and linker flags used by NDK builds?  Right now we're hacking things by looking through the cmake files created when you add C++ to an Android Studio project.

The problem is that the vast majority of the time we're building many existing 3rd-party projects that each have their own build systems.  Rewriting the build systems to use Android's tools (the cmake and ndk-build systems) would be insane; we need to use the existing make systems, and the vast majority of the time that means we need to provide things like CFLAGS, CXX_FLAGS, CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS, etc to configuration scripts.  And those sets of flags aren't documented anywhere that I've found, other than by watching the output of native Android ndk builds.

UPDATE:  I think I wasn't quite clear on exactly what I wanted.

We had some nasty scripts that managed to suck the right set of flags out of an existing build using cmake.  (One of those projects where you say it'll take you twenty minutes, and you're laughably wrong.).  Those scripts broke with r16 beta 1.  I'd really not have to write nasty unstable scripts just to pull out flags, since they'll probably break with the next ndk release anyway.

(Here's the last output from our scripts, in case you'd like to see the flags I'm talking about: https://gist.github.com/banshee/15f1a5fbce0c71af6498656bb02ebc67)

Answer (score 2):

Try examine

```
{SDK_PATH}/ndk-bundle/build/core/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/setup.mk
```

or different toolchain (that depends on what you'are building). There are flags needed for cross-compilation defined.

EDIT

I've done some digging.

If you edit a file:

```
{SDK_PATH}/ndk-bundle/build/core/definitions.mk
```

and find a line `define  ev-compile-cpp-source`. Or maybe better `define ev-build-file`.

You can add there

```
$(info $_FLAGS is [${_FLAGS}])
```

before `$$eval`.

Now if you build something, you'll see flags.

Comment: It's not at all straightforward to get from those setup.mk files to the full set of flags passed to the linker and compiler, though - that's the problem.  For example, no setup.mk file sets the -mstackrealign flag, and you'll see that in a cmake build (for x86).

Answer (score 1):

For custom build systems you should use a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html). That'll handle getting all the basic flags right for targeting Android. It won't handle any of the decisions best left to the build system though such as optimization level, debug flags, etc.

EDIT:

Unfortunately your current solution is as good as it can get for the time being. Eventually the toolchain configuration will be moved into JSON files in `$NDK/meta` like a few (trivial) things already have so we can share that info between ndk-build and CMake, but that's not happening any time soon.

Comment: That's just rephrasing the question though.  What flags to you get automatically when you build and use all of those toolchains?  (And yes, I know I can read through the code, I'm just wondering if there's a way to do this that will survive changes to the ndk.) . AFAIK, just using those prebuilt toolchains doesn't get you the right set of arguments; even the documentation at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html talks about more flags that you need to add.

Comment: "What flags to you get automatically when you build and use all of those toolchains?" Are you asking about which flags are needed to build binaries for Android, or the full set of flags that ndk-build might choose to use?

Comment: Updated the question.  I want the full, exact set of flags that ndk builds normally use, for every (architecture * debug|release) combination, for C, C++, and linking shared libraries and static libraries.  And I want to not mess around with scripts to figure it out every time ndk updates happen.  While I'm at it, I want C and C++ flags split up correctly (some projects combine them for C++ flags, some don't, unfortunately). And I want a pony for my birthday.

Comment: Sadly the pony might be the easiest part right now. Updated my answer.

Comment: I think cmake actually does end up providing what I need, although I needed to hand-build some combinations of flags.  Added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use cmake to drive configure, or to write out the values in whatever format you need.

For example, here's a CMakeLists.txt file that configures and compiles the expat project.  It expects the source for expat to be on the system already.  Probably most of what you want is in the standard_configure_env macro; it's the modified CFLAGS etc that you'll want.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project (expat)

macro(standard_configure_env output)
set(${output}
    CC=${ANDROID_C_COMPILER}
    CXX=${ANDROID_CXX_COMPILER}
    CFLAGS=--target=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET}\ --sysroot=${ANDROID_SYSROOT}\ \ --gcc-toolchain=${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}\ ${ANDROID_COMPILER_FLAGS}
    CXXFLAGS=${ANDROID_COMPILER_FLAGS_CXX}
    AR=${ANDROID_AR} 
    RANLIB=${ANDROID_RANLIB}  
    LD=${CMAKE_LINKER}  
    LDFLAGS=${ANDROID_LINKER_FLAGS}
)
endmacro()

include(ProcessorCount)
ProcessorCount(nCpus)

set(expat_output_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/expat)
set(expat_build_dir ${expat_output_dir}/expat_bin)
set(expat_install_dir ${expat_output_dir}/install)
set(expat_src_dir /Users/james/yourpathgoeshere/cmake/expat/src/expat-2.1.0)

set(markers_dir ${expat_output_dir}/markers)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${markers_dir})

set(expat_copied ${markers_dir}/copied)
set(expat_configured ${markers_dir}/configured)

set(expat_final_lib ${expat_install_dir}/lib/libexpat.a)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${expat_install_dir}/include)

standard_configure_env(configure_env)

set(configure_host ${ANDROID_HEADER_TRIPLE})
# expat doesn't understand these Android architectures, so set them by hand to what expat can
# use
if(${configure_host} STREQUAL aarch64-linux-android)
set(configure_host arm-linux-android64v8a)
elseif(${configure_host} STREQUAL armv7-linux-androideabi)
set(configure_host arm-linux-androideabiv7a)
endif()

set(configure_args
    --host=${configure_host}
    --disable-shared
    --prefix=${expat_output_dir}/install
    --exec-prefix=${expat_output_dir}/install
    )

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${expat_configured}
    COMMAND ${configure_env} ./configure ${configure_args} && touch ${expat_configured}
    DEPENDS ${expat_copied}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${expat_build_dir}
    )

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${expat_copied}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${expat_src_dir} ${expat_build_dir}
    COMMAND touch ${expat_copied}
    )

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${expat_final_lib}
    COMMAND make -j${nCpus} installlib && touch ${expat_final_lib}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${expat_build_dir}
    DEPENDS ${expat_configured}
    )

add_custom_target(expat_build DEPENDS ${expat_final_lib})
add_library(expat STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(expat expat_build)

set_target_properties(expat
  PROPERTIES
  LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${expat_install_dir}/lib/libexpat.a
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${expat_install_dir}/include)
```

Thanks to @DanAlbert and @JakubPiskorz for pointing out that I really do want to get this from cmake.